# What is the best data structure to extract elements in descending order in O(1) time

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, sorting, c++11, boost

I insert elements as we do a certain operation and try to get the elements in the order of insertion(which is considered the element's age). `priority_queues` could be used but since they are implemented as heaps, the operation to visit the top element is O(1), but to get the next element in the next iteration I have to do a `pop()` along with the call to `top()`. `pop()` is log(n). I am thinking if I should just use a regular `queue` to add elements whenever I would add it into the `priority_queue` and keep `pop`ing from the queue to get elements in the order of their addition time. My confusion is that since we have a multi-threaded application, could there be elements out of order and so would be safe to visit all elements to make sure. This would make it `O(n)`. Can somebody help me in my choice of the data structure to use?

Should I just go ahead with a `priority_queue` and get elements in `O(log n)` everytime? Or use a stack and assume the guarantee of the order of elements and get elements in O(1) everytime? Or use a totally different data structure?

Please keep in mind that this is implemented in VC++ and have access to boost.

Would like views on this. Thanks!

Comment: "I insert elements as we do a certain operation and try to get the elements in the order of insertion" ... Why is this not just a FIFO queue?

Comment: Yes, that's why I was thinking if I should just use a queue (FIFO) but was contemplating since it is multithreaded and might mess up the order somehow. If they will never happen I will rather use that.

Comment: Does each thread need its own queue? Or might you need something like this: http://www.ridgesolutions.ie/index.php/2014/01/31/c-thread-safe-blocking-queue-using-boost/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Since, what you are looking for is a simple FIFO, I suggest you to use some thread safe queue, And I am sure boost has already implemented some thread safe queue like [message queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/message_queue.html).